# Woocommerce adding custom product count to products only in specific category and in specific page

Tags: woocommerce, counter, categories, product, shortcode

I have caught onto some of the logic but battling with how to implement:

- display my custom product count only on products in a specific product category
- also display product count only on a specific custom WP page (which I used the `product_category` shortcode)

My code in functions.php is as follows and it does add the `$top50_counter` value before the product thumbnail but it is doing it site-wide, hence why I need to narrow it down as per my points above.

```
/* ADD NUMBERING TO TOP 50 LIST PRODUCTS */
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_before_shop_loop_item', 5);
$top50_counter=1;
function custom_before_shop_loop_item() {
  global $top50_counter;

  echo '<h1>'.$top50_counter.'</h1>';
  $top50_counter++;
}
```

I'm assuming I have to use the `$terms = get_the_terms` function in there somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`is_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) and [`has_term`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) conditionals. Try re-factoring the code to the following.

```
/* ADD NUMBERING TO TOP 50 LIST PRODUCTS */
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_before_shop_loop_item', 5);

$top50_counter=1;

function custom_before_shop_loop_item() {

  global $top50_counter;

  /* Replace 42 with the actual page ID and "your-category" with the actual category slug */

  if( ( is_page( 42 ) ) || ( has_term( 'your-category' , 'product_cat') ) ):
      echo '<h1>'.$top50_counter.'</h1>';
      $top50_counter++;

  endif;
}
```

P.S: untested code.

Comment: Anand thanks. The only logical issue I found in your code where the IF is, the `||` which is logical OR should instead be a logical AND `&&` because if it's OR, it will activate the numbering code on other pages. I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thank you, appreciated and I learnt something today.

Comment: I am glad I could help. I initially had used `&&` but then after re-reading your question got a bit confused and changed it to logical OR, see my edit :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Use corresponding category name and custom wp page slug in the following function.

```
function custom_before_shop_loop_item(){
    global $post, $term, $top50_counter;
    $id = $post->ID;
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';
    $terms = get_the_terms( $id, $taxonomy );
    if( ($terms[0]->name == 'Category Name') || ($post->post_name == 'custom-wp-page-slug') ){
        echo '<h1>'.$top50_counter.'</h1>';
    }
    $top50_counter++;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If successful, `get_the_terms` will return an array, so `$terms->name` will not work. Fix your code to run the `if` check in a loop `foreach( $terms as $term ) {  if( $term->name == 'Category Name' .....` Also the `$top50_counter++` should be inside the `if` condition, only increment it when the product has that specific category.

Comment: Thank you guys, with all the variations of tackling the problem, it makes more sense to me and I've learnt something. I have marked the first answer as accepted although I'm sure your code will work too. Appreciated.